# Does existence of variance and covariance of two random variables implies existence of variance of their sum?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

If $X$ and $Y$ are random variables such that $Var(X)$, $Var(Y)$ and $Cov(X,Y)$ exist and are finite, is it true that $Var(X+Y)$ also exists (and is finite)?

I know that the converse doesn't need to be true. For example, if $X \sim Cauchy$, then $-X \sim Cauchy$, and $$0=Var(0)=Var(X-X)$$ so variance of the sum of $X$ and $-X$ exists, but $Var(X)$, $Var(-X)$ and $Cov(X,-X)$ don't.

Comment: Only the existence of $\mathrm{Var}(X)$ and $\mathrm{Var}(Y)$ is needed. The existence of covariance is a corollary by Cauchy-Schwarz. So is $\mathrm{Var}(X+Y)$.

Comment: @CaveJohnson thanks. Do you have any source with the proof of that corollary?